# How to add one more field in disqus form

Tags: 7, comments

i have been installed disqus module in my drupal setup.it gives only one textarea field how to i add one more field to get subject from user.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disqus does not provide titles, therefore, it is not possible.

What the Disqus module does is embed the Disqus chat/comments as an iframe. For security reasons, you cannot modify/alter anything that is inside an iframe.

Comment: Is it possible to add another field in disqus itself. i mean disqus admin panel

Comment: @udhayakumarUK really? I never seen a Disqus that has multiple fields. If it's possible, then you would have to do it through Disqus. Login to your Disqus account, and see if there is some sort of option to allow for multiple fields.